# Android BLE scan in background mode of app, Advertisement packets are not detecting beacons are detecting

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

Is anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? 
For the long run of BLE scanning. Once the app goes into background mode then app stops detecting advertisement packets.

- I am using default BLE scan process. with scan filter as BLE device's
  address and beacon manufacturer data.
- In scan settings, I am using .setScanMode(SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).
- I am using android 8 and Android 9 devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oreo has background execution limits.

> - Apps that are running in the background now have limits on how freely
>   they can access background services.
> - Apps cannot use their manifests
>   to register for most implicit broadcasts (that is, broadcasts that are
>   not targeted specifically at the app).

One way to solve this problem would be to use foreground service, so android system won't kill it.

More info:
[android-8.0-changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! unfortunately, I am using foreground service to overcome this background limit.

Comment: @Parth Do you see foreground service notification when you start service??